# Ways to get list of extensions in Firefox, Safari, Google Chrome or Opera?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, safari, opera

I have small idea to add social to extensions galleries (show suggest via Facebook friends), but I never develop any extensions, so I want to ask professionals.

Do your know ways to get list of extensions in Firefox, Safari, Google Chrome or Opera?

Comment: You want to programmatically retrieve a list of extensions that the current user has installed in their browser? Or you just want a list of extensions that you can use as examples in developing your own?

Comment: I want to programmatically retrieve a list of extensions that the current user has installed in their browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opera has no such feature. We are concerned that the list of extensions is private information the user may not want exposed, and we are unsure if it might have security implications to share this information, so it's not likely to happen.

Answer (score 2):

- Firefox:
  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/extension-list-dumper/
- Safari: ~/Library/Safari/Extensions/Extensions.plist
- Chrome: chrome://extensions/
- Opera: Ctrl+Shift+E

Answer (score 1):

Chrome: Use chrome management APIs [Chrome Management](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#type-ExtensionInfo)

```
chrome.management.getAll(function callback)
```

Firefox: Use AddonManager APIs [AddonManager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager#getAddonByID%28%29)

```
AddonManager.getAllAddons(function(addons)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox, you can use MR Tech Toolkit to do that.